# Using Image Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, stream, bitmap

Hi i have been looking for a solution to display images in image control that is inside the list box.I have seen to set image source and assigning it `new BitmapImage(new Uri(stringX))`.

Not in my case i first retrieve all the images from URL using `WebClient` that is in function and that function returns `MemoryStream` after some process.

Now what i want to do is display that image so i don't have Uri to create new bitmap.So i tried to Implement `StreamSource` but i get

```
  Set property 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.StreamSource' threw an exception.
```

here goes my code

**Retrieve Image From Web**

```
public MemoryStream GetImage(string id)
        {
            WebResponse result = null;
            Image rImage = null;
            MemoryStream imageStream = null;
            try
            {
                string url = "https://devnmark.com/" + id + "/picture";
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                result = request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = result.GetResponseStream();
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
                byte[] rBytes = br.ReadBytes(1000000);
                br.Close();
                result.Close();
                imageStream = new MemoryStream(rBytes, 0, rBytes.Length);
                imageStream.Write(rBytes, 0, rBytes.Length);
                rImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true);
               // imageStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception c)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (result != null) result.Close();
            }
            return imageStream;

        }
```

**Class Declared for Type**

```
 class UserInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public MemoryStream Picture { get; set; }
    }
```

**Load Images**

```
 private void LoadFriends()
        {
            foreach (dynamic imge in MainList)
            {
                if (x >= 6)
                    break;
                UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
                info.Id = int.Parse(imge.id);
                info.Name = imge.name;         
                info.Picture = function.GetImage(info.Id.ToString());
                FriendList.Add(info);
                x++;
            }
            list.ItemsSource = FriendList;
        }
```

**XMAL for ListBox**

```
<ListBox x:Name="list"  Margin="18,100,535,74" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Height="50" Width="50">
                 <Image.Source>                                    
                   <BitmapImage StreamSource="Picture" ></BitmapImage>
                 </Image.Source>
             </Image>
             <my:RibbonCheckBox Label="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />                    
          </StackPanel>                     
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>      
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you mind telling **what** exception that was thrown?

Comment: I have mentioned it in question

Comment: no the Exception should be like `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`,  `ObjectDisposedException` or similar. You should also tell on what line the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a big bunch of problems.

```
byte[] rBytes = br.ReadBytes(1000000);
```

What if the image is larger than 1MB?

Remove the line

```
rImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true);
```

You don't use the result from that, it just will take processing time and position the imageStream at the end.

You should probably use [`MemoryStream.Seek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx) to reset the stream to it starting position before returning.

```
imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

**Edit**

Your XAML binding is wrong

```
<BitmapImage StreamSource="Picture" ></BitmapImage>
```

Should be

```
<BitmapImage StreamSource="{Binding Picture}" ></BitmapImage>
```

to be a valid binding, but I'm actually not sure if you can bind `StreamSource` at all or if you need to initialize from code, like in the example at the very bottom of the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx).

Comment: Still getting Exception mentioned above

Comment: @Afnan, You have still not told anyone **what** exception was thrown.

Comment: Exception Title = `XmlParseException `
and it reads Set property **'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.StreamSource' threw an exception.**

Comment: @Afnan That is probably because your binding is incorrectly declared, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes this was the problem.Thanks you helped me alot.

Comment: @Afnan, I guess you see how carefully inspecting the exception gives important clues to what part of the code might be wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

The website seems to require some sort of authentication as far as I can tell.
Did you provide that?
Could you give us a working url?

Comment: the problem is not in the website if gives the result and if i add a break point i see that there is an BitmapImage there